# Lost files when creating a git new git repository. Any way to recover?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Honestly, I'm at a complete loss as to what happened. I created a new repository for my chess engine that i'd made some drastic changes to. Because it had a git repo previously I deleted the gitattributs/ignore/.git and went to create a new repo in the folder. When I tried to create a repo in the new folder I got a bizarre screen showing my old program with a branch or something. This was all done through the git GUI and I didn't look at it very long so i'm not exactly sure what it was showing.

Regardless, now my new folder/repo is identical to the old folder and I've lost a days worth of work. All that I have left is the new release EXE which works, but can't help me unless I can decompile and get all the files out of it?

Some how I overwrote all my new work before I could get it up on github and now the new folder is identical to the old. Is there any way I can recover the files I've lost? It was also a visual studio project, but the backups in VS2015 for all my projects are empty, so no luck there.

Comment: It is not clear to me as to what/where you were doing. For example, at first you say you deleted `.git` folder and say that you tried to create a new repo **there**, and then you say you tried to create a new repo in **new** folder. Etc.  Please include example paths (even if c:\foo and c:\bar) just to indicate it better. First of all, you should have read messages :) and shouldn't have deleted .git until 100% sure you've finished, but you know that already.

Comment: Right now it sounds to me like you have a few copies of your project, probably kept along with new/old/older repos. It's strange that your files on the disk were "rolled back". It's hard to achieve unless you use `-f (--force)` options, or unless you use `reset` command, which you have not mentioned. For that reason, **it is more probable** that you simply have mistaked the folders. Double or triple check paths and locations, maybe your project is OK and is simply located on a different drive/folder/etc that you think. grep/filesearch is your friend there.

Comment: I copied an my engine folder, C:\p\Engine and created a new folder C:\p\newEngine deleted the git stuff inside the new folder. Then used the git gui to create a repo at C:\p\  named newEngine. Which is how i've done it in the past. Something obviously got messed up somewhere however

Comment: Finally, having a working EXE along with DLLs, if you wrote it in C# or any other **managed** language, then you actually can decompile it relatively easily. You will lose things like local variable names, some lambdas or yield-returns may start looking strange, but you will probably get a compilable code and fix the aesthetics afterwards. It's hard to find a good free decompiler, but most of the commercial ones have xxx-day trial modes, so.. well.. good luck, I've gotta go now :/

Comment: Definitely not the wrong folder, I really wish it was. I created it today, it's in a folder of five others, and the only thing remaining from my updated project is the x64 folder which my old project didn't have, containing the updated exe

Comment: Thanks man, it's written in c++ sadly :(